# Density matrix and entangled states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

I am studying the density matrix formalism. I gather that:

1. the trace of a density matrix, $tr(\rho)$ is always 1,
2. if $tr(\rho^2) < 1$ we have a mixed state, otherwise a pure state,
3. if $\rho$ cannot be diagonalized, we have an entangled state.

Is my understanding correct?

**Correction**: as per comments, $\rho$ being *hermitian*, it is *always diagonalizable*, and 3. is thus false.

Comment: $\rho$ can always be diagonalized, because it is necessarily Hermitian. Otherwise, 1. and 2. are correct.

Comment: As to 3, there is no simple way to decide if a mixed state is entangled.